# on Continuous and Open Functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. If $f$ is a continuous function from $X$ **onto** $Y$, then $f$ is open.

I am asking can the above result be proved. I am aware of the following cases:

If $f$ is bijective then it is homeomorphic and the closed map lemma [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps)

Answer (score 4):

ASCII art counterexample:

```
    /
 /\/
/
```

No, a continuous surjection of compact Hausdorff spaces need not be open.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true: Here is an example:

Let X be a finite, discrete topological space. It is hausdorff, because it is discrete. And compact, because it is finite. We consider a constant map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and a indiscrete, topological space. Then its not open. Because f(x) is not open for every $x\in X$.

Comment: A finite Hausdorff space is discrete, and every map to a discrete space is open.

Comment: My Y is not discrete, it is indiscrete. So only Y and $\emptyset$ are open in Y. A constant map, maps every Subset of X (which is open by definition) into a fixed $a\in Y$, which cant be open, if Y is not one-elemental.

Comment: Well, the question stated that both spaces are compact **Hausdorff** spaces.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didnt saw that. Maybe i can fix it :)

Comment: How about this: We take Y=[0,1] as subspace of $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. Then [0,1] is compact and hausdorff, but a constant map as above is not open.

Comment: The map shall be onto, i.e. surjective.

Comment: Oh, shame on me! My english is not so good (iam from germany), i though he wanted to say, into instead of onto :/

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for your reply and comments. Being available of a counterexample means there is a GAP in proving it. Could you please tell me what is wrong in this: Given an open set $G$ in $X$, $X\setminus G$ is compact. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(X\setminus G)=Y\setminus f(G)$ is compact and hence closed, so $f(G)$ is open.

Comment: @Layman $f(X\setminus G) = Y\setminus f(G)$ generally doesn't hold (unless $f$ is bijective). There may be points $a\in G$ and $b\in X\setminus G$ with $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was thinking that surjectivity is enough for such equality. I really thank you for your comment. Besides your example  seems interesting but this is the first time I hear it.

Comment: With $X=[-1,1]$, $Y=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x^2$ you can see that the equality does not hold.

Comment: @Balla Thanks for your efforts.